# Crystal Reports including multiple records with queries

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a database table named ORDERS that contains repair order data and invoice data.  Each record has an ORDERTYPE (i.e. INVOICE or REPAIR) and all invoice records have a system-generated ORDERID that links them to the repair orders (called the REFORDERID).

I have a second database table called ORDERLN that contains all individual line items for the repair orders and invoices.  I need to access this data selectively to retrieve sales and cost information.

I need to limit my selected report data by the INVOICE DATE, which is contained in the ORDERS table.  I have been trying to limit the report's record selection by DATE and INVOICE TYPE but that restricts me to only working with INVOICE data.  I need sales data, which is on the invoice and I can get this easily, but I also need cost data which is only on the repair order, hence my need to query that data as well.

I need a way to first restrict the invoice close date, then pull in the invoice data AND pull in the repair order data.  The link to the repair order data must be made via the REFORDERID records.

Can anyone guide me either with record selection formulas or SQL queries?

Thanks,
John

Comment: SQL query is the way to go. Let the database do what it does best. If you try to do this in Crystal Reports, it can be resource intensive and inefficient. If you do not have a lot of rows to process, it may be okay to do this in Crystal Reports. What database platform is all this data in? It sounds like you know where to get your data. You just need to practice joining data together.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're missing here. If you select INVOICE type records in a date and join them to their corresponding REPAIR type records (via an alias of the ORDERS table with *no* record selection performed on it) then wouldn't that give you everything you need?

Comment: @Ryan problem is not with the data...everything is available but problem is how to limit the records with date filtering..

Comment: @Siva, I did what you suggested before but the problem is that it restricts the data set to ONLY invoice data from the ORDERLN data table.  I need to use the REFORDERID from the ORDERS table (which is a data point for each invoice that references the underlying repair order) to also pull in repair order line item data from the ORDERSLN table.

When I filter the record selection by Invoice Type, it restricts the output to only invoice data.  The ORDERLN table contains line item data for the invoices AND repair orders, and this $ data is different because it's sales data vs. cost data.

Comment: @John.. to understand more, you need to add how you have joined the tables and if possible example of records you wish to see in report.

Comment: @Siva: All tables have left outer joins.  The problem is the data set is restricted to invoices only with that selection parameter set to "invoice".  See the following link to an image of the ORDERS data table.  Notice the REFORDERID on the invoice line, which references the associated repair order's ORDERID.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98094305/orders.jpg

Comment: in the ORDERSLN table, the repair orders has its own line items with COST data (total lines depend on # of parts used) and the invoice has its own line items with SALES data.  I have all the sales data in my report working, displaying sales by part and invoice order ID.  However, I can't get the part cost data for the repair order line items to display because the REFORDERID (in the ORDERS table) is nested within each invoice record.  If I don't limit the data by invoicetype="invoice" I can get the cost data to work; however, I need to filter the whole dataset by invoice closed dates.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the report.  Notice the cost data is the same as the sales data.  This is because it's filtering the invoicetype="invoice" and then can't pull the repair order data in the ORDERSLN table.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98094305/partcost.jpg

Answer (score -1):

`As per your requirement and explanation.. below is my approach...`

1. Link the `ORDERS` and `ORDERLN` tables in database expert.
2. To limit the data create 3 parameters `Start Date`, `End Date` and one parameter for `Invoice type`.
3. In record selection formula write below formula.

If you are picking the invoice date form `ORDERS` then

```
ORDERS.Invoice Date>={?Start Date} and ORDERS.Invoice Date<{?End Date} and 
ORDERS.Invoice Type={?Invoice Type}
```

Above selection will pick the user required date and invoice type from database.

1. Now place the fields you need in the report design

Comment: @Downvoter... Provide your solution for the problem and then vote others down